# What is the common order for variables, constants and numbers in math typesetting?

Tags: math-mode

I am setting my documents in LaTeX and am satisfied with the appearance of the output. Besides this, I am always in doubt how I have to arrange variables, constants and numbers.

Let's talk about the following example:

```
\begin{align*}
F &= \frac{\textrm{d}W^{'}_{\textrm{mag}}}{\textrm{d}x} \\
&= -\frac{N^2 I^2 \mu_0 a d}{8e^2}.
\end{align*}
```

Is there a rule which variable or constant should come first? Is it better to place points (like `\cdot`) between those variables? Do I order the symbols alphabetically and how do I deal with capital letters?

Comment: Formulae don't consist of random objects, every variable and constant has a meaning. Arrange them by meaning, too.

Comment: That is indeed true. So you would recommend to order everything in groups like "group of distances", "group of electrical constants", ...

Or what would you say to the above example?

Comment: Is this on-topic? Might be more suitable for math.se or physics.se.

Comment: Should I move it?

Comment: Not about your question, but your code can be improved.  First, the prime `'` is already a superscript, so just write $W'$.  Second, don't use `\textrm` to get words like `mag` in math; use `\text` from the `amsmath` package, which looks better.  Third, rather than writing `\textrm{d}`, try running `\newcommand\dd{\mathrm{d}}` (`\mathrm` is better since it is, after all, math) or, better still, `\DeclareMathOperator{\dd}{d}` (using `amsmath` again), and then write `\dd W`, `\dd x`, etc.  Your papers will look better and be easier to write.

Comment: I agree that this is off-topic as it is about convention.  My *guess* is that if you ask on maths.sx or physics.sx then the most useful answer will be of the form "Take a look at similar articles and do what they do.".  (All the others will be of the form "I do *this* because I always have done" or "I read that *X* said do *that* so I that's what I do")

Comment: Thanks for the code-improvements. I think, I should just do as proposed and follow my favorite auther (who is not determined yet). :-)

Let's see, if I manage to mark this question as answered.

Edit: It is closed already.